# css-background-image not working

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've used this particular rule in CSS over 100 times but for some reason it is not working.
Im using CSS to define the background of a Background div. The div is working because if I change the `background-color` it works.  Can someone please help me im stumped.

```
html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Paint</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/Css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Js/Js.js"></script>
        <div id="Background">
        <div id="Wrapper">
       <canvas id="Canvas">
       </canvas>       
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#Background
{
        background-color:#ffffff;
        background-image:url('Images/Background/Anfield.png');
    height:1000px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: auto;
}
```

File path is Images/Background/Anfield.png

Comment: try putting it in the same directory as the script

Comment: Pretty sure z-index doesn't work on statically positioned elements by the way.

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately so it cant be the path name.

Comment: Since your css is in a different folder, you need to go back a folder: ../Images/Background/Anfield.png

Comment: Your code worked perfectly fine for me, except that since I didn't have your server setup I just pointed the background-image url to an absolute url (https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png). My guess is that your relative path to your image is off somehow.

Comment: it seems to working fine http://jsfiddle.net/MZu9a/

Comment: You should start off on the right foot and get your indentation in order, and I can see you having all sorts of unnecessary problems with the way you are using title case. Just a suggestion. I would say keeping things lowercase is going to save you from trouble. Also, z-index isn't going to work without the element being position: absolute; or position: relative; --- try using some other images too -- as a test to make sure it's not something else -- "http://placehold.it/1600x800/ff0066&text=Test" or something. I also wouldn't use those id's instead of classes unless you have a good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CSS file is in `Css/Css.css`, then you first would need to go up a folder. so then it turn out as follows:

```
#Background
{
     background-image:url('../Images/Background/Anfield.png');
}
```

Comment: Awwwwwww dang i get ye brain lapse thanks very much :)